# Losing network connectivity when starting Visual Studio

Tags: windows, networking, visual-studio

I am doing development remotely over RDP and all of a sudden I have a very strange issue: whenever I launch Visual Studio (2010), the remote machine loses all network connectivity for about 15 minutes (at which time it comes back).  I am not sure exactly when it started, but it was fine a few weeks ago.

Really hard to debug remotely and there is nothing in the event logs.

Has anyone seen this issue before?  Suggestions?

Comment: No. Reinstall. Never seen that and VS should not trigger that.

Comment: That would be a very last resort - trying to avoid that for obvious reasons...

Comment: WOuld be my first step. Unless you run a debugger, VS is a complete user level appliation. If that results in RDP issues there is a fundamental problem. Check your drivers.

Comment: This is solved; it was somehow caused by Resharper (8.1.23.546). I could start VS fine in SafeMode and the moment I uninstalled Resharper, the problem went away. I then tried to reinstall it, and the problem came back. I am not sure how Resharper could cause this, but it did (or at least it triggered whatever the root problem was).

Lastly, some more details on the problem: when starting VS, the network icon in the tray bar would show "No Internet access" and you could no longer reach anything over the network. After 10 minutes the network access would come back.

Comment: What the heck? Resharper is also a user level program and I totally fail to see how that should trigge that. Damn.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more data, in case it helps somebody.  I did a fresh install of a VM with Windows Server 2008 R2, but the same issue!

I contacted JetBrains support, and they requested that I start Visual Studio with these switches:  "devenv /ReSharper.LogFile C:\resharper_log.txt /ReSharper.LogLevel Verbose"

to collect Resharper log data.  When I did, the machine lost network (as always), and it took several hours to come back.  The log file was 3.7 GB(!) with millions of this line:
Thread:25: [ULCCC] Received from=x.x.x.x:63300, windowUserName=joe userName=Joe Doe

So it appears to basically DOS itself somehow.

I heard back from JetBrains and they asked me to try to change the license to Eval (instead of registered), and it handled the issue.  I am waiting to hear back on a more permanent solution.  So it is basically a flaw in their license check mechanism.

Comment: Time to start laughing. THis is the first time I hear of a software ddos'ing the server it is installed on. OUCH. A SERIOUS issue in their licensing. THey better fix that one - fast. Grats for finding it.